# Render the results of an Action to a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

How can I render the results of a Controller Action to a string in MVC 3 (So I can send them as an email)?

Comment: I don't think so.  The answers there look like they're for MVC2 WebFormViews.  I don't know how to make them work with MVC3 Razor Views.  And I'm trying to render the result of a controller action, not necessarily render a view.

Comment: then maybe a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)?

Comment: If I used WebClient it wouldn't be in the context of the current user I don't think?  The user is logged in but the WebClient wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is probably this:

```
string body = Html.Action("Mail").ToHtmlString();
```